# Will an element be garbage collected if there is a reference to its field?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I.e., in

```
class A {
    public String s;
}
```

and

```
A a1 = new A();
a1.s = "bla";
A a2 = new A();
a2.s = a1.s;
a1 = null;
```

will `a1` be garbage collected or is the reference to `a1.s` permitting it from being collected (and I should rather do a deep copy, `a2.s = new String(a1.s)`)?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If an `object` holds a reference of another `object` and when you set container object's reference `null`, child or contained `object` automatically becomes eligible for garbage collection.

See [this link](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/04/garbage-collection-in-java.html#ixzz2XrmpLgrv) for further information.

Comment: @MarounMaroun does this hold good for String literals? that is, the String literal `s` is still referenced by `a2`.. so ?

Comment: @MarounMaroun ... Your link was a very good read on Java's GC.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @sanbhat Instances of String created at runtime are subject to garbage collection just like every other object.

Comment: AFAIK In Java 7, string literals are held by the class which is held by the class loader.  Only when this is unloaded will the String be freed. (I suspect this varies between JVMs)

Answer (score 4):

Since `A` has only a **reference** to `s`, `a2.s` pointing to `a1.s` **would not affect** `a1`'s garbage collection.

i.e `a1` is eligible for GC, but the object referred to by `a2.s` (or `a1.s`) will not be eligible for GC.

Answer (score 3):

The object A1 is eligible for GC as now it is set to be null. But as String "bla" in not available for GC because it also referred by a2.s. So only a1 object is available for GC.

If this is the case

```
A a1 = new A();
a1.s = "bla";
A a2 = new A();
a1 = null;
```

then both a1 object and "bla" is available for GC. Because all references of "bla" is removed but now the case is

```
a2.s = a1.s;
```

a2 is refering to same string "bla". So string is available in stringpool not for GC

Answer (score 1):

Here you are creating **two references** of `Object A` like `a1` and `a2`.

First, you are assigning value of `a1` to `a2`.So after setting value to `a2`, `a1` is allowed for GC. But there will be no change in `reference a2`.

You can also check this blog for [Garbage Collection](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-garbage-collection.html):