# Will be an object garbage collected if there is a reference to it from another object?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

[It is not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418665/will-an-element-be-garbage-collected-if-there-is-a-reference-to-its-field), I would like to know about this in context of C#.

I have such classes:

```
public class A
{
    public List<string> AList { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public List<string> BList { get; set; }
}
```

Imagine, that in `row 6` happens Garbage Collection:

```
1 row: A objectA = new A();
2 row: B objectB = new B();

3 row: objectA.AList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
4 row: objectB.BList = objectA.AList;

5 row: objectA = null;
6 row: //Garbage collection occurs
```

I have two questions:

1. **Will be `objectA` garbage collected? If yes, why? Cause, in my view these objects will be created in a heap like in the following image**:
   [image]
2. My second question is **whether the following image is correct about how objects will be allocated in a heap. I mean, is `objectA.AList` placed inside a circle(the above image) or near the circle(the following image)**:

[image]

Comment: So I'm not sure about this answer, so hopefully somebody with a better understanding will be able to answer, but as I understand it objects that have no references to them whatsoever _should eventually_ be garbage collected, nothing else needed. An object needs active scope eventually (up the chain of references) to the currently executing program in order not to be garbage collected. Once that's gone it's fair game for the collector, whenever it runs.

Comment: This takes 2min to check. But logic dictates in my head, yes as objectB.Alist contains a refference to Alist so if Alist is altered so is the result of objectB.Alist as it is Alist. So if Alist equals null so does objectB.Alist. So the content of Alist is GC'ed. But the object Alist is not, it is now null

Comment: @HenkHolterman please, see my distinct question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293387/how-is-memory-allocated-when-you-create-a-property-of-class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the variable that `objectA` refers to will be - or at least *may* be garbage collected. There's *nothing* referring to it any more. (There's no guarantee that it will collected "soon", but it's *eligible* for garbage collection.)

The list that `objectA.AList` referred to won't be garbage collected, because `objectB.BList` now refers to it.

The problem with your first diagram is the idea that one object is "inside" another. That's not how it works - an object just maintains a *reference* to another, but each object is effectively an independent piece of memory... and if there are no references from anything to a particular object, it's eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: thanks for answer! Am I right that if I create new field(not a proprety) `int k` in `objectA`, then `k` will be placed somewhere in a heap, but not inside `objectA`?

Comment: @StepUp: No, `k` would be part of `objectA`, just like the field backing `AList` is - but the *value* of the field backing `AList` is just a reference, it's not the list object. It might be worth you reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010172/what-is-the-difference-between-a-variable-object-and-reference/32010236#32010236