# How is memory allocated when you create a property of class?

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have the following class:

```
public class A
{
    public List<string> AList { get; set; }
}
```

Then I create object of a class:

```
A objectA = new A();
objectA.AList = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3" };
```

My question is **how memory will be allocated in a heap? I mean will be `objectA.AList` allocated inside of `objectA` (image1) or as a separate object in a heap(image2)**

Image1:

[image]

Image2:

[image]

Comment: Consider that your call of `new List<string>` could be at any point in time - it could be in another function, and could be called well before or well after your call to `new A()`, and stored in any number of intermediate variables. How do you expect the runtime to predict the future and know that it will *eventually* be assigned to a particular `A` object's `AList` property?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever consequently the answer is the `Image2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct answer is : Image 3.

I'm not going to draw this but your example leads to 5 objects on the Heap.

Objects (instances) don't have names but they are referred to by the following references:

1. objectA
2. objectA.AList
3. objectA.AList[0]
4. objectA.AList[1]
5. objectA.AList[2]

Each string is also an object on its own.

The `objectA` instance only contains a reference to the List, and the List holds an array of references to strings. 3 are used, more might be allocated and still be `null`.

None of these objects lives 'inside' another.